# Upgrade to 5.35.1. - Events no longer working

Tags: civievent, upgrade

I have just upgraded civi to **5.35.1.** on my Drupal 7 build but now when I go to 'configure event' I get a whole load of code before the tabs...and then the info/settings page is blank.

Please see attached screenshot.

I use 'civirules', 'cividiscount' and 'NCN Civirules Actions for Zoom' extensions ties in to events but even if I disable these I am faced with the same issue.

I am completely stumped and wondered if anyone has had a similar issue?

Regards
Robbie

[image]

Comment: Do you have any print statements?

Comment: Hi Pradeep...sorry, what do you mean print statements?

Comment: Are you able to check for js errors? (normally you right click in your browser & choose console or something like that to see them)